# Best location for Solr index files

Tags: debian, solr

I'm trying to setup properly Solr under a debian machine. It's working ok but the I'm not sure where's the best location for the index files. Currently they are inside the application's folder but I don't really like this approach. I was thinking some of the following :

- /var/lib/solr/index-name
- /var/solr/index-name
- /usr/share/solr

I like the first cause it follows debian's convention but the second is more obvious to me. Any thoughts???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd go with the first: `/var/lib/solr`. Why?

Following the [FHS on the var](http://www.debian.org/doc/packaging-manuals/fhs/fhs-2.3.html#THEVARHIERARCHY) folder:

1. There is a set of predefined folders inside var. It doesn't mean that you cannot add more, but you could prefer not to make it dirty.
2. The `/var/lib` is where programs store the variable information they need to run. (Correct me if I'm wrong but I guess mysql uses `/var/lib/mysql`, for example).

Comment: Regarding 2 : Yes, mysql goes there and I guess also redis goes there, etc, etc so I guess yes it makes sense...